# Deploy Reactapp using Docker & SSL

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile, ssl-certificate

## Dockerfile

Docker run command : `docker run -itd -p 8080:80 prod`

```
FROM node:16-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
COPY . /app/

RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@4.0.3 -g --silent
RUN npm run build
# production environment
FROM nginx:1.21.1-alpine
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

## defalut.conf file

```
server {

listen 443 ssl default_server;
listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/sites-available/cert.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/sites-available/ssl.key;

server_name ipaddress;

location / {
proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

I am unable to see my index.html file running on my ip Address in https. its working fine with `http://ipaddress:8080`. Above is the Configuration File of DockerFile & default.conf file. nothing is showing in server logs.

I want to know that is the above configuration is correct or esle how to deploy react-app using Docker & SSL & Nginx

Comment: What do you see in browser? Can you please add `docker run` command you are using in your question? Or contents of `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: Docker run command : docker run -itd -p 8080:80 prod

Comment: The `proxy_pass` line seems wrong; `localhost` is the Nginx container, and the React application is just static files here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Looking at your comments it looks like your port configuration is not correct, in NginX port listening is set to listen on port `443`, but your docker port configuration is using port `80` as host port. Assuming Node server is listening at port `8080`, docker run should be like this

```
$ docker run -itd -p 443:443 prod
```

And try `https://ipaddress` , based on certificate setting you should see either warning in browser (if certificate is not trusted fully, you might need to add it as an exception), or see proper contents.